# How to POST video to Facebook through Graph API using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api, post

The code found in the documentation uses a `<form method="POST"` to post a video to a profile:

```
// Using the page access token from above, create the POST action
// that our form will use to upload the video.
$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/" . $page_id . "/videos?"
      . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc
      . "&access_token=". $access_token;

// Create a simple form
echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' "
       method="POST">';
echo 'Please choose a file:';
echo '<input name="file" type="file">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
echo '</form>';
```

What's the cleanest way to post from a URL without using a form?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have already uploaded the video on your server...

```
  $config = array();
  $config['appId'] = 'appID';
  $config['secret'] = 'secretID';
  $config['fileUpload'] = true; 
  $config['cookie'] = true;

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);  


  $video_details = array(   
            'access_token'=> 'user publish token',
            'message'=> 'Test video!',
            'source'=> '@' .realpath($videosPathOnServer)   

    );

 $post_video = $facebook->api('/'.$usersFacebookID.'/videos', 'post', $video_details);
```

As far as I remember, by default all videos visibility is set to Friends and their Friends

Comment: Hi shpat, that's for the php-sdk right? I just want to use the graph API. I've read the only option is to use cURL and then post a local file. How would I go about assigning the cURL'd video file to $post_url and have it function with my code above?

Comment: @shpat - This solution has made my day... A lot of thanks.... :)
A lot of anger on documentation - Why this is not available on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/videos#publish

Comment: @DominicKirkwood - you can look at here - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/

Comment: Video sharing working fine by above code but is there any way that we can post video on friend's time line?

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia Have you tried replacing $usersFacebookID with friends userid?