# PHP - Posting video on Facebook through Graph API using a valid access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I have a video exist on my server,
I need to post that video on Facebook using Graph API.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/) is the code suggested by Team Facebook.

What I am doing is as below.

1) From an Android device I am getting an access token

2) Recognizing user by passing that access token to Facebook and get email id and through email id recognize user

3) Posting user's video from my server to Facebook through Graph API.

4) Returning a video id to android device as an API response.

I am approaching this route because in Android device it is 2 step process to post video on Facebook.

1) Download the video first

2) Post to Facebook

This is time consuming.

Here is the code that I am trying

```
    define("FB_WEB_APP_ID","********");
    define("FB_WEB_SECRET","********");
    define("FB_WEB_REDIRECT_URI","<< redirect url >>");
    $GLOBALS["all_user_dir_path"]="/var/www/proj/web/video/user_videos/";
     define("FB_WEB_SCOPE","user_friends,email,public_profile,user_hometown,user_location,user_photos,user_videos,publish_actions,read_friendlists,publish_stream,offline_access");
    define("FB_WEB_RESPONSE_TYPE","code%20token");

    $GLOBALS["fb_app_creds"]=array();
    $GLOBALS["fb_app_creds"]['appId']= FB_WEB_APP_ID;
    $GLOBALS["fb_app_creds"]['secret']=FB_WEB_SECRET;
    $GLOBALS["fb_app_creds"]['response_type']=FB_WEB_RESPONSE_TYPE;
    $GLOBALS["fb_app_creds"]['redirect_uri']=FB_WEB_REDIRECT_URI;
    $GLOBALS["fb_app_creds"]['scope']=FB_WEB_SCOPE;
    $GLOBALS["facebook"] = new Facebook($GLOBALS["fb_app_creds"]);



class DefaultController extends Controller
{
// some code....

/**
     * @Route("/gk",name="_fb")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function gkAction(Request $request){

        $facebook = $GLOBALS["facebook"];

        $access_token=$request->query->get("access_token");

        if(!$access_token){
          die("give access token in url.......");
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);

        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        $me=$facebook->api("/me");

        $email=$me['email'];

        $all_user_dir_path=$GLOBALS["all_user_dir_path"];
        $user_directory = str_replace(array(".","@"), "_",$email);

        $user_dir_abs_path=$all_user_dir_path.$user_directory;

        print_r($me);

        $video_file_path=$user_dir_abs_path."/video.mp4";

        if(file_exists($video_file_path))
        { 
          echo "file exists...";
        }else{
          die("not exist");
        }

        $video_title="Test";
        $video_desc="Test";

        $access_token=$request->query->get("access_token");

        $file = "@".$video_file_path;
        $data =  array('name' => 'file', 'file' => $file);

          $post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?"
         . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc
         . "&". $access_token
         ;


        echo "<hr>TRY 1<hr>";
        try{
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            $res = curl_exec($ch);

            $video_id=0;
            if( $res === false ) {

            }else{
              $res=json_decode($res,true);
              /* $video_id = $res['id'];*/
               echo ":::: ";print_r($res);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
       }catch(\Exception $e){
           echo " Exception generated in Try 1 : ".$e->getMessage();
       }

       echo "<hr>TRY 2<hr>";

       $params = array(
            "access_token" => $access_token,
            "name"=>"file",
            "file" => "@".$video_file_path,
            "title" => $video_title,
            "description" => $video_desc
          );
          try {
              $ret = $facebook->api('/me/videos', 'POST', $params);
              print_r($ret);
          } catch(\Exception $e) {
            echo " Exception generated in Try 2 : ".$e->getMessage();
          } 

        die("</pre>");
    }    

}
```

Output I am getting is `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.` error and `(#353) You must select a video file to upload.`

Look at this image

[image]

Please tell me how to solve this problem ??

New code tried...................................................

```
 /* code with sdk - object oriented way */
        $file=$GLOBALS["all_user_dir_path"].$user_directory."/video.mp4";
        $source = array();
        $source['name']="video.mp4";
        $source['type'] = "video/mp4";
        $source['tmp_name'] = $file;
        $source['error'] = 0;
        $source['size'] = filesize($file);
        echo "<br><br>$file<br><br>";

        $params = array(
          "access_token" => $access_token, 
            "source" => $source,
            "title" => "testvideo",
            "description" => "testvideo"
        );
          try {
              $ret = $facebook->api('/me/videos', 'POST', $params);
              echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
              echo "<pre>";print_r($ret);echo "</pre>";
          } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
          }
```

but this gives `(#353) You must select a video file to upload` error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
public function shareSocialgrationFB($access_token,& $exception){
        $video_id=0;

        try{
            $config = array();
            $config['appId'] = FB_WEB_APP_ID;
            $config['secret'] = FB_WEB_SECRET;
            $config['fileUpload'] = true; 
            $config['cookie'] = true;
            $facebook = new Facebook($config);
            $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);  
            $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);

            $me=$facebook->api("/me");
            $email=$me['email'];

            $user_directory = str_replace(array(".","@"), "_",$email);

            $file = $GLOBALS["all_user_dir_path"].$user_directory."/video.mp4";

            $usersFacebookID=$facebook->getUser();
            $video_details = array(   
                      'access_token'=> $access_token,
                      'message'=> 'Testvideo!',
                      'source'=> '@' .realpath($file),
                      'title'=>'Test'   
            );
            $post_video = $facebook->api('/'.$usersFacebookID.'/videos', 'post', $video_details);
            $video_id=$post_video['id'];
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            //echo "Exception generated :: ".$e->getMessage(); 
        $exception=$e->getMessage(); 
        // extra code to handle exception
        }
        return $video_id;
    }
```

Reference : [How to POST video to Facebook through Graph API using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228638/how-to-post-video-to-facebook-through-graph-api-using-php)

I don't know why the info about configurations

```
$config['fileUpload'] = true; 
$config['cookie'] = true;
```

is not mentioned at below official docs of APIs

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/videos#publish

However solution given above, worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`file` is not a valid parameter. Instead of parameter `file`, use **`source`**.

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/videos)

Comment: used that, but still not working.. as in the reference it is mentioned source should be encoded as form data, I tried to create similar array of file which we get in $_FILES.. not get success.
can you share a code snippet in which video file is getting posted on FB with SDK, without sdk I have done it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279064/unable-to-upload-video-to-users-facebook-account-using-graph-api

Comment: I have added new code to question please see... what value should I pass to **source** parameter ??

Comment: @Gaurav the solution that link contains is based on this official doc of Team Facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/ , but that is not the object oriented way and needs redirection. my requirement is achieve task object oriented way - i.e. using Facebook PHP SDK

Answer (score 0):

For FB SDK4+Composer: (see the hardcoded video path, and the encoding).

Doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

FB requests the video file to be passed encoded as form-data: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

private function postFBVideo($authResponse, $filePath, $formDataMessage)
    {
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('yourAppkey', 'yourAppSecret');
        $ajaxResponse = '';
        try {
            $session = new FacebookSession($authResponse->accessToken);
        } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
            // When Facebook returns an error
            $ajaxResponse = 'FB Error ->' . json_encode($ex) ;
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            $ajaxResponse = 'FB Validation Error - ' . json_encode($ex) ;
        }
        if ($session) {
            $response = (new FacebookRequest(
                $session, 'POST', '/me/videos', array(
                    'source' => new CURLFile('videos/81JZrD_IMG_4349.MOV', 'video/MOV'),
                    'message' => $formDataMessage,
                )
            ))->execute();
            $ajaxResponse = $response->getGraphObject();
        }
        return json_encode($ajaxResponse);
    }
```